# Stability analysis using the Jacobian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I must find the steady states, the Jacobian, and the stability of each point.

$x' =x^2 - y^2$
and $y' = x(1-y)$

Simply solving for when these equations equal zero, I found that $y=0,1$, after getting $y-yy=0$, as must x, as $x^2=y^2$.

Thus I believe the steady states to be $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ but I don't understand the Jacobian matrix. I think it is:

$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2x-y^2 & x^2-2y \\
   1-y & x-1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

So for the state (0,0):

$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   1 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

So, the trace of the matrix is $1$ and the determinant is $0$. Is this neutral center?

For (1,1):

$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

So the trace and the determinant are both $0$ (how do we characterize this)

Any help would be appreciated, as would work checking, am new to differential equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: You are missing an equilibrium point.

$$\dot{x}=0=x^2-y^2 \implies x=\pm y$$
$$\dot{y}=0=x(1-y) \implies x=0 \text{ or } y=1$$

Using $x=0$ for the first equation we see that $y=0$, which implies the first equilibrium at $(0,0)$.

Using $y=1$ for the first equation we see that $0=x^2-1\implies x=\pm 1$, which implies the second and third equilibrium points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$.

Using $x=\pm y$ for the second equation we obtain:

$$0=\pm y (1-y) \implies y = 0 (x=\pm 0) \text { and } y = 1 (x=\pm1).$$

Hence, in total we only have three equilibria: $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$.

The Jacobian of your system is given by:

$$J =\begin{bmatrix}2x & -2y \\ 1-y & -x\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, your task is to evaluate the Jacobian at the equilibrium points.

You can then determine the eigenvalues of the system and discriminate three cases:

- All eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ have real part strictly smaller than zero ($\operatorname{Re}(\lambda_i)<0$ for all $i$) -> You can conclude asymptotic stability for the nonlinear equilibrium point.
- You have at least one eigenvalue with real part strictly greater than zero ($\exists \lambda_i \text{ such that } \operatorname{Re}(\lambda_i)>0$)-> You can conclude instability for the nonlinear equilibrium point. The equilibrium points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ do belong in this category.
- All eigenvalues have a real part which is smaller or equal to zero and you have at least one eigenvalue with a real part of zero -> Linearization does not yield any stability information (this case is sometimes referred as the critical case). The equilibrium point $(0,0)$ belongs in this category. A stability analysis can be carried out if one is able to find a proper Lyapunov function.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm curious, do you know how to classify the stability when both the trace and the determinant of the matrix are zero? Regardless, you're right, I'm missing one.

Comment: @HRM: You should not use the trace & determinant classification. It is only valid for two-dimensional systems. It is better to always calculate the eigenvalues or use the Hurwitz criterion to determine asymptotic stability.

Comment: @MrYouMath could you please advise where can I find a proof of this classification using the eigenvalues? does it have a theorem name?

Comment: What about when you have one eigenvalue lower than zero, one greater than zero and one equal to zero (would it be unstable or saddle)? also what happens if all eigenvalues >=0 (would it be critical or unstable)?